# Сортировка столбцов Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, сортировка, pandas

Изучил множество топиков на сайте по этому вопросу, но либо там делается совсем не то, что мне нужно, либо я не разобрался. Если повторяюсь - извините.
Задача следующая:
Имеется Тета-матрица с частотным распределением, выглядит она так:

```
              0        1        2        3  ...  10752
topic_0    2.5897    2.5047   5.8036    1.0      4.0316
topic_1    5.7798    1.5601   6.7843    0.0      1.4447
topic_2    8.0836    3.4020   2.2702    0.0      9.65861
```

Это матрица, в которой 3 строчки (по кол-ву тем) и почти 11 тысяч столбцов (по кол-ву документов в моделировании). Мне нужно, чтобы в левой части собрались столбцы с наибольшими значениями, не теряя при этом номер столбца. Понимаю, что это можно сделать только для соответствующей строки по отдельности. Итог я вижу примерно так:

```
            11232      1345        9       9854   ...   3
topic_0    10.5897    10.5047   9.8036    9.3584        1.0
```

Как отсортировать столбцы по значению по убыванию не теряя их индекс для соответствующей строки?
Более простой пример:

```
          0   1   2
topic_0   1   5   3
topic_1   0   2   1
topic_2   3   6   7
```

Выходные данные при сортировке по первой теме (строке):

```
          1   2   0
topic_0   5   3   1
```

Выходные данные при сортировке по второй теме (строке):

```
          1   2   0
topic_1   2   1   0
```

И по третьей строке:

```
          2   1   0
topic_2   7   6   3
```

Это покажет нам, что наибольшее влияние на тему 0 и 1 оказывает первый документ, а не тему 2 - второй документ.

Comment: Можете уточнить вопрос? Какой должен получиться результат для данного DF: `df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'topic_0': {'0': 1, '1': 5, '2': 3},'topic_1': {'0': 0, '1': 2, '2': 1},'topic_2': {'0': 3, '1': 6, '2': 7}}, orient="index")` ?

Comment: @MaxU добавил в основной пост, чтобы было наглядней. Надеюсь теперь станет яснее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример исходного DF:

```
In [83]: df
Out[83]:
         a  b  c
topic_0  1  5  3
topic_1  0  2  1
topic_2  3  6  7
```

решение:

```
res = {i:df.loc[i].sort_values(ascending=False) for i in df.index}
```

результат:

```
In [14]: res
Out[14]:
{'topic_0': 1    5
 2    3
 0    1
 Name: topic_0, dtype: int64, 'topic_1': 1    2
 2    1
 0    0
 Name: topic_1, dtype: int64, 'topic_2': 2    7
 1    6
 0    3
 Name: topic_2, dtype: int64}

In [15]: res["topic_0"]
Out[15]:
1    5
2    3
0    1
Name: topic_0, dtype: int64

In [16]: res["topic_0"].to_frame().T
Out[16]:
         1  2  0
topic_0  5  3  1
```

---

```
In [17]: res["topic_2"]
Out[17]:
2    7
1    6
0    3
Name: topic_2, dtype: int64

In [18]: res["topic_2"].to_frame().T
Out[18]:
         2  1  0
topic_2  7  6  3
```

Comment: Но ведь так потеряются индексы столбцов, правильно понял? В моем случае индексы означают номер документа, и с помощью сортировки я выясню какие документы оказывают наибольшее влияние на соответствующую тему. Очевидно, что всю матрицу сразу отсортировать не выйдет. У разных тем будет разные столбцы на первом месте. Их надо сортировать по очереди (дропая другие строки), но как сортировать сохраняя индекс (номер документа)?

Comment: @AndrewFitcher, сначала покажите в вопросе как должен выглядеть выходной DF для приведенного мною примера, тогда сможем поговорить о том как это реализовать ;)

Answer (score 1):

На вашем частичном примере:

```
              0       1       2    3    10752
topic_0  2.5897  2.5047  5.8036  1.0  4.03160
topic_1  5.7798  1.5601  6.7843  0.0  1.44470
topic_2  8.0836  3.4020  2.2702  0.0  9.65861
```

Добавляем ряд с суммами колонок матрицы, затем сортируем по этому ряду:

```
df.loc['sums']= df.sum()
df=df.sort_values(by='sums', axis=1, ascending=False)
```

Получаем:

```
              0     10752        2       1    3
topic_0   2.5897   4.03160   5.8036  2.5047  1.0
topic_1   5.7798   1.44470   6.7843  1.5601  0.0
topic_2   8.0836   9.65861   2.2702  3.4020  0.0
sums     16.4531  15.13491  14.8581  7.4668  1.0
```

Можно также сразу удалить ряд с суммой, если он вам не нужен:

```
df=df.sort_values(by='sums', axis=1, ascending=False).drop('sums')
```

Результат:

```
              0    10752       2       1    3
topic_0  2.5897  4.03160  5.8036  2.5047  1.0
topic_1  5.7798  1.44470  6.7843  1.5601  0.0
topic_2  8.0836  9.65861  2.2702  3.4020  0.0
```

Comment: Извиняюсь, может недостаточно точно сформулировал проблему, но это не то, что мне нужно. Я расписал всю таблицу, чтобы лучше был понятен контекст, но видимо зря.
Каждая строка - это разная тема (в тематическом анализе) и соответственно у каждой темы будет свой порядок "самых больших столбцов". Как видите в результате у Вас в первой теме идут числа 2, 4, 5, 2. А должно быть строго по убыванию от большего к меньшему. В этом весь смысл. 
Может надо сначала дропнуть все остальные строки и сортировать Вашим методом по одной?